# Send a pdf file as base64 in POST

Tags: java, android, json, pdf, base64

I want to send a pdf file to an endpoint url via POST but it requires to be in base64. There are other parameters I will be sending in the JSON, but cant figure out how to convert the pdf file to base64 and add it to the JSON.

Would it be easier to just use a base64 converter on the web and copy the text and paste it as a String in the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can base64 encode in java like this.

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("Test".getBytes());
String pdfInBase64 = new String(encodedBytes);
```

And then add pdfInBase64 to your post.

Comment: where would I add the path to the pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

since java 8 yo can do:

```
    byte[] inFileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pdfFileName)); 
    byte[] encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(inFileBytes);
    System.out.println(encoded.length);
```